# Encode the UTF8 formate body content of a Mail into text/html formate in Ruby On Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, imap

I am trying to create email app for Gmail by using `Net:IMAP` library in Ruby On Rails.

When retrieving the mails, the body content of mail was in `UTF8` charset format, that's why I am unable to display the content in Plain text/html formate

I am getting the body in the following formate. I want to convert into text/html

```
{
    "seqno": 1,
    "attr": {
        "BODY[]": "Delivered-To: esmobtest@gmail.com\r\nReceived: by 10.170.119.65 with SMTP id l62csp1679922ykb;\r\n Wed, 24 Dec 2014 04:01:59 -0800 (PST)\r\nReturn-Path: <sravanthibhimpati@gmail.com>\r\nReceived-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of sravanthibhimpati@gmail.com designates 10.194.92.148 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.194.92.148\r\nAuthentication-Results: mr.google.com;\r\n spf=pass (google.com: domain of sravanthibhimpati@gmail.com designates 10.194.92.148 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=sravanthibhimpati@gmail.com;\r\n dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com\r\nX-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.194.92.148])\r\n by 10.194.92.148 with SMTP id cm20mr63961124wjb.88.1419422518561 (num_hops = 1);\r\n Wed, 24 Dec 2014 04:01:58 -0800 (PST)\r\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;\r\n d=gmail.com; s=20120113;\r\n h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;\r\n bh=B2GYwyRDMnyFlpelNUy/xQyE1AhF2c0igx3W+m9DN3E=;\r\n b=s4feUXdaNnN0oXVP+2yJxq544gD6KxmYfivQExZXEMYCBTMdOCP3AqhvK0/zzZyo9W\r\n t7vB+7WGcoGmKDBblRZdv+xrEhuyPrKsVWtN6ufmpGBzIntz4RpWq8afH1cK9FRgtDjh\r\n uNu6DgnvCHD7AVYGY0JhjoHQfLcyyqEeCjSntDFErGlTeyrTgaK9vxDpKZqsPkT51NcS\r\n Yob/G88PIqqIwzEBIcjsIhYPgUo6lbUekvhbhBjjtrY4C4Bc3DDnSWR8oyRIDETHjsBJ\r\n toemc3ib0SBdvRXx+6q4YHYKfybq3raBuvJcjN0G6iOgqWxVwBwKwJonQNDtOfgukDLj\r\n PnNQ==\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nX-Received: by 10.194.92.148 with SMTP id cm20mr63961124wjb.88.1419422518555;\r\n Wed, 24 Dec 2014 04:01:58 -0800 (PST)\r\nReceived: by 10.194.36.133 with HTTP; Wed, 24 Dec 2014 04:01:58 -0800 (PST)\r\nDate: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 17:31:58 +0530\r\nMessage-ID: <CAPooJOYExFiD-ALxtJSW_6UP_+s5=cVqP1Gq_50Gx+y=ZBr8_g@mail.gmail.com>\r\nSubject: Test mail\r\nFrom: Sravanthi Bhimpati <sravanthibhimpati@gmail.com>\r\nTo: esmobtest@gmail.com\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7bfd01660141aa050af50fe7\r\n\r\n--047d7bfd01660141aa050af50fe7\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\nHi esmob,\r\n\r\nThis is test mail.\r\n\r\n-- \r\nThanks & Regards\r\nSravanthi.B\r\n\r\n--047d7bfd01660141aa050af50fe7\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n<div dir=\"ltr\"><div>Hi esmob,<br><br></div>This is test mail.<br clear=\"all\"><div><div><br>-- <br><div class=\"gmail_signature\"><div dir=\"ltr\">Thanks &amp; Regards<div>Sravanthi.B</div></div></div>\r\n</div></div></div>\r\n\r\n--047d7bfd01660141aa050af50fe7--\r\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the full body.  You need to use a MIME parser and extract the parts you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You need a full blown MIME parser for this. This situation is analogic to a person needing a file a form which was delivered by snail mail in an envelope. Before you can fill in that form, you have to open the envelope, go through the enclosed stuff, locate the correct form, read its instructions on how to fill it, and only then you can proceed with doing actual work. The situation you described is an equivalent of handling the full, still wrapped package within a sealed envelope.